# Installing flat pedals (with pins) on a MTB for rainy/wintry conditions?

Tags: maintenance, pedals, winter, preventative-maintenance, rain

I have some [RaceFace Chester pedals](https://www.raceface.com/products/chester-pedal) that I want to install on my beater MTB, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea. Basically, I have two bikes and I want to use one for the "bad" weather conditions (rain/snow).

I've never ridden in the rain or snow before, so I wanted to know: would it be a bad idea if I installed those Chester pedals on my beater bike for riding in the rain/snow? I guess I don't know if the pins will rust out on me in those conditions, or if the plastic casing will just crack from cold temps and road salt. (I live in Boston.) In that case, would it be better to get all metal pedals?

Comment: I think you will have to try yourself. I have used plastic Crankbrothers Candy in winter and it does not crack. Also, the bike is in a shed where it freezes in winter. The plastics should withstand that, but if it is less then -20°C it could be a different matter.

Comment: Since you already have the pedals, you may as well use them, unless you have other plans for them.  If the plastic pedals fail, then replace them in the future.  If nothing else it delays the cost.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that a decent-quality plastic platform pedal like yours shouldn't crack in Boston conditions (which are not as bad as Wisconsin or Alaska!). However, if you haven't used metal-pin platform pedals before, be careful of your shins -- the pins will do a number on any flesh they dig into if your foot slips off the pedal or you put your foot down on the ground.
I've switched to platform pedals with molded plastic "pins" to avoid the shin damage, but I don't ride in frozen areas.